# Assume that dim(V ) = dim(W) and there exists an S ∈ Hom(W, V ) such that T ◦ S = IW . Show that T is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

V and W be finite dimensional vector spaces over F and let T ∈ Hom(V, W). Assume
that dim(V ) = dim(W) and there exists an S ∈ Hom(W, V ) such that T ◦ S = IW . Show
that T is an isomorphism.
here i cant take, dim V = dim W  implies as it is not given that one is a subspace of other.so how to show it??.Also could you specify weather it is valid in the infinite case also.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: nope.cant u do something other than that

Comment: A quick proof using the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem):
$T \circ S = \operatorname{id}_W$ implies $T$ is surjective, and so, $\dim (\operatorname{im}T) = \dim(V)$. Hence $\dim(\ker T) = 0$, which means that $T$ is injective.

Comment: can u at least say weather it works for infinite

Comment: Please explain what is the meaning of the equation "$\dim(V) = \dim(W)$" when $V$ or $W$ are not finite-dimensional.

Comment: both V and W are infinite vector space ,i guess

Comment: The symbol $\dim(Z)$ for an infinite-dimensional vector space $Z$ is meaningless. Anyway, there is no way of which the statement is true: consider the real vector space $V$ of all polynomials functions $p : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, and let $T: V \to V$ such that $T(p) = p'$ for all $p \in V$. Then, if $S: V \to V$ is the linear map such that, for $p \in V$, $S(p)$ is given by $$S(p)(x) = \int_0^xp(t)dt \quad \textrm{for all $x \in \mathbb R$} ,$$ we obviously have $T \circ S = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R[x]}$, but $T$ is not even injective.